# Static website now capable of being expanded to allow users

Tags: html, vs-web-site-project

I am planning to develop a website for a cause that will eventually become a blog-like site where I will post things about the cause and the users can comment on it.  There will be other functions and stuff for users though. It will probably be done through rails or something similar but isn't important to decide yet.

But I can't take on that large a project yet and can't afford to support storing user accounts.  So I plan to start out by making static pages of all the pages I will eventually have.  Is there a way I can do this to make it compatible with my future plans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a CMS. Find what your hosting provider supports. And then select a good CMS that is familiar, or has lots of support/low learning curve.

I would not recommend making a static page. Most CMS programs dont allow you to import static pages directly.